# v8 access to DOM

Tags: dom, v8

I want to change the v8 engine in order to be able to intercept every access to DOM elements.
As you know, v8 does not create the DOM tree. The browser creates the DOM tree.

- My question 1:  how/where in the v8 source code, the DOM memory structure is delivered to v8.
- How can I do my interception with minimum effort?

Answer (score 3):

The code that registers the DOM elements with V8 is not within the V8 source code, it's in another part of the Chromium source: third_party/WebKit/Source/

There are a few pieces in there which are probably of interest to you:

- core/dom: This directory contains the implementations of the base DOM classes, plus IDL definitions of them which are used to generate the interfaces to V8
- core/html: Same, but for HTML-specific classes
- bindings/scripts: I believe this is where the scripts live which convert the IDL into C source which interfaces with V8 (I haven't looked into this part in much detail)
- bindings/core/v8: This is where the code is which actually calls into V8 to execute scripts, etc

Edit (2020-05-27): This stuff has moved around in recent versions of Chromium. As of chromium 83 (and I think at least back to around chromium 75), it's now under:

- third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/
- third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/
- third_party/blink/renderer/bindings/scripts/
- third_party/blink/renderer/bindings/core/v8/

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you exactly where the DOM is registered in V8, but I have some hints for you about where you can start your search. First, as the browser creates the DOM, you should also look in the browser, not v8. If you found the spot where the DOM is registered in V8 you'll also see what code in V8 is called for this.

In chromium, [Frame](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/page/Frame.cpp&q=frame%3a%3acreate&exact_package=chromium&l=205) is the class that contains a webpage. Throughout its creation, it instantiates a [ScriptController](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/ScriptController.cpp&l=102) object which itself creates a [V8DOMWindowShell](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/V8DOMWindowShell.cpp&l=193). The passed in [DOMWrapperWorld](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/DOMWrapperWorld.h) and its [DOMDataStore](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/DOMDataStore.h) maintain the mapping from DOM to JS objects.

This doesn't exactly tell you where the DOM is registered in V8 but somewhere around you should find this. Using Eclipse and let it search for references of seemingly interesting methods in the chromium project or list the call hierarchy are good tools for such research.

**P.S.**: As I'm needing something similar myself, I came across `/src/out/Debug/gen/webcore/bindings` which is a directory that gets created and filled with all the templates for the DOM objects during compilation of Chromium. You could edit them as you wish and recompile with your changes.

If you find the script that generates them, you could probably attach interceptors for them all at once.

Comment: In the source code of the v8, in object.cc file, there ar4e arrays of methods named SetProperty and Getproperty. These are methods where I currently intercept. And I found that the DOM is kept in the form of Objects in the v8. Objects inheret maybeObject class and they have a hashtable of attributes, childs, etc. The root Object which is the documnt, is the root of the DOM tree. Of course there are some caching mechanisms out there as well, but I could not figure out the exact mechanism. Anyways, I have been able to do some primitive interception.

Comment: I don't know where you want to go with your interception, but when I searched a way to incorporate Information Flow tracking, I also came across these methods. The main problem I had there was that during runtime in the interception I didn't know anything about the context in which it occurs (Is a property read written to the next SetProperty call? How many subsequent property reads belong together? etc.) If you want to do something similar, think about that first before you spent effort there. (I ended up with AST rewriting.)

Comment: I want encrypt/decrypt the values. When they are assigned, they should be encrypted, and then used in expressions (for example math), their value should be decrypted. But I did not think about AST. It should be working, I will check it now. The problem with my current solution is that it seems there are different instances of the same object in v8. For example, I guess that v8 creates different instance for a value of object when an assignment is done. What do you think?

Comment: I didn't want to say that you have to go for the AST. Its just that I found the context information that I required for handling statements and expressions there. However, I don't understand the essence of your problem: What do you mean by different instances for a value and of which object(s)? Objects are basically a closure around a set of properties. All properties that refer to objects have an identity, i.e. the same and equal values are distinguishable. How it works with primitives I don't know exactly. But as they are not meant to have an identity, this shouldn't be a problem.